# Radius test only success in the local machine, but can't success remote machine

Tags: freeradius, radius

I install the freeradius in centos7 through ./configure&&make&&make install.
after make the server running. the local test is valid:

```
[root@iZ2zebgsn1haj8gu0447fiZ raddb]# radtest steve testing localhost 0 testing123
Sending Access-Request of id 151 to 127.0.0.1 port 1812
User-Name = "steve"
User-Password = "testing"
NAS-IP-Address = 172.17.120.248
NAS-Port = 0
Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
rad_recv: Access-Accept packet from host 127.0.0.1 port 1812, id=151, length=71
Service-Type = Framed-User
Framed-Protocol = PPP
Framed-IP-Address = 172.16.3.33
Framed-IP-Netmask = 255.255.255.0
Framed-Routing = Broadcast-Listen
Filter-Id = "std.ppp"
Framed-MTU = 1500
Framed-Compression = Van-Jacobson-TCP-IP
```

But in the remote machine, it seems that there's no response from the radius server machine:

```
[root@iZ2zebgsn1haj8gu0447fiZ raddb]# radtest steve testing 211.71.149.221 0 testing123
Sending Access-Request of id 149 to 211.71.149.221 port 1812
User-Name = "steve"
User-Password = "testing"
NAS-IP-Address = 172.17.120.248
NAS-Port = 0
Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Sending Access-Request of id 149 to 211.71.149.221 port 1812
User-Name = "steve"
User-Password = "testing"
NAS-IP-Address = 172.17.120.248
NAS-Port = 0
Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
Sending Access-Request of id 149 to 211.71.149.221 port 1812
User-Name = "steve"
User-Password = "testing"
NAS-IP-Address = 172.17.120.248
NAS-Port = 0
Message-Authenticator = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
radclient: no response from server for ID 149 socket 3
```

Here's my configure file:

clients.conf：

```
client 211.71.149.221{
    ipaddr=211.71.149.221
    secret  = testing123
    short   = test-client
    nastype = other
```

}

users

```
steve   Cleartext-Password := "testing"
    Service-Type = Framed-User,
    Framed-Protocol = PPP,
    Framed-IP-Address = 172.16.3.33,
    Framed-IP-Netmask = 255.255.255.0,
    Framed-Routing = Broadcast-Listen,
    Framed-Filter-Id = "std.ppp",
    Framed-MTU = 1500,
    Framed-Compression = Van-Jacobsen-TCP-I
```

I didn't use database,so I didn't make a change to the radiusd.conf.

```
[root@iZ2zebgsn1haj8gu0447fiZ raddb]# netstat -upln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           727/dhclient        
udp        0      0 172.17.120.248:123      0.0.0.0:*                           828/ntpd            
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           828/ntpd            
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           828/ntpd            
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:58664           0.0.0.0:*                           26159/radiusd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5489            0.0.0.0:*                           727/dhclient        
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:18120         0.0.0.0:*                           26159/radiusd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1812            0.0.0.0:*                           26159/radiusd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1813            0.0.0.0:*                           26159/radiusd       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1814            0.0.0.0:*                           26159/radiusd       
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                828/ntpd            
udp6       0      0 :::54457                :::*                                727/dhclient
```

Answer (score 0):

Your failing radtest is sending the request to a remote server with IP 211.71.149.221. Your clients.conf defines a client with client IP-adress 211.71.149.221. I'm guessing that that is NOT the IP from which your request is coming from.